# how to enable binary function in informatica power center 10.5

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

From KB article, I got that To use binary functions, set the environment variable INFA_ENABLE_BINARY_FUNCTIONS to True or Yes in both server and client.
Can anyone please help me with how to add the environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

To use binary functions, you need to set the environment variable

`INFA_ENABLE_BINARY_FUNCTIONS` to True or Yes.

Follow below steps

1. Goto informatica Administrator
2. Select service
3. Under environment variables, click edit  New
4. Here you need to enter the name of the binary variable which is  `INFA_ENABLE_BINARY_FUNCTIONS` and for value give True
5. Click Ok and restart the service.
6. Make sure all power centre applications are closed before you edit in administrator.

Comment: The OP has stated that they already know that they need to set this environment variable. They are asking for help in *how* to do that, which you have not (yet) provided. Consider editing your answer so that it addresses the *actual* question.